# What to try when apt-get install XXX results in Connection failed

Tags: apt

Is there something wrong with the repository, the server, or is my cache stale?

I am able to `ping tw.archive.ubuntu.com` just fine.

It almost seems like the file

```
http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pulseaudio/pulseaudio_1.0-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb
```

doesn't exist.

**EDIT:**

Looks like the server I'm pointing to may be stale.  I found the missing file [here](http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pulseaudio/).

It looks like you can check on whether servers are [up to date](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors).

I'm going to look into how to change my server now.

```
$ sudo apt-get install kcachegrind
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  docbook-xsl exiv2 gstreamer0.10-alsa gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio icoutils kate-data katepart kde-runtime kde-runtime-data kdebase-runtime kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdoctools kubuntu-debug-installer libasound2-plugins libattica0
  libcanberra-pulse libclucene0ldbl libdbusmenu-qt2 libdlrestrictions1 libexiv2-10 libilmbase6 libiodbc2 libkatepartinterfaces4 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4 libkdecore5 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4 libkfile4 libkhtml5
  libkidletime4 libkio5 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkmediaplayer4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkparts4 libkpty4 libkrosscore4 libktexteditor4 libnepomuk4 libnepomukquery4a libnepomukutils4 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libopenexr6
  libphonon4 libplasma3 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libqapt-runtime libqapt1 libqca2 libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-designer libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-qt3support libqt4-script libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-svg
  libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libqtwebkit4 libraptor2-0 librasqal3 librdf0 libsolid4 libsoprano4 libspeexdsp1 libssh-4 libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0 libthreadweaver4 libutempter0 libvirtodbc0 libxml2-utils libyajl1
  ntrack-module-libnl-0 oxygen-icon-theme phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer plasma-scriptengine-javascript pulseaudio pulseaudio-esound-compat pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils qapt-batch qdbus rtkit shared-desktop-ontologies soprano-daemon
  virtuoso-minimal virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common
Suggested packages:
  docbook-xsl-doc-html docbook-xsl-doc-pdf docbook-xsl-doc-text docbook-xsl-doc libsaxon-java libxalan2-java docbook-xsl-saxon fop xalan dbtoepub libterm-readline-gnu-perl libterm-readline-perl-perl kcachegrind-converters khelpcenter4 djvulibre-bin
  hspell libqca2-plugin-cyrus-sasl libqca2-plugin-gnupg libqca2-plugin-ossl libqt4-declarative-folderlistmodel libqt4-declarative-gestures libqt4-declarative-particles libqt4-declarative-shaders qt4-qmlviewer libqt4-dev qt4-qtconfig raptor2-utils
  rasqal-utils librdf-storage-postgresql librdf-storage-mysql librdf-storage-sqlite redland-utils phonon-backend-vlc phonon-backend-xine phonon-backend-mplayer gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly pavumeter paman paprefs pulseaudio-module-raop
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  docbook-xsl exiv2 gstreamer0.10-alsa gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio icoutils kate-data katepart kcachegrind kde-runtime kde-runtime-data kdebase-runtime kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdoctools kubuntu-debug-installer libasound2-plugins
  libattica0 libcanberra-pulse libclucene0ldbl libdbusmenu-qt2 libdlrestrictions1 libexiv2-10 libilmbase6 libiodbc2 libkatepartinterfaces4 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4 libkdecore5 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4 libkfile4
  libkhtml5 libkidletime4 libkio5 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkmediaplayer4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkparts4 libkpty4 libkrosscore4 libktexteditor4 libnepomuk4 libnepomukquery4a libnepomukutils4 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0
  libopenexr6 libphonon4 libplasma3 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libqapt-runtime libqapt1 libqca2 libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-designer libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-qt3support libqt4-script libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql
  libqt4-svg libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libqtwebkit4 libraptor2-0 librasqal3 librdf0 libsolid4 libsoprano4 libspeexdsp1 libssh-4 libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0 libthreadweaver4 libutempter0 libvirtodbc0 libxml2-utils libyajl1
  ntrack-module-libnl-0 oxygen-icon-theme phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer plasma-scriptengine-javascript pulseaudio pulseaudio-esound-compat pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils qapt-batch qdbus rtkit shared-desktop-ontologies soprano-daemon
  virtuoso-minimal virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common
0 upgraded, 107 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 918 kB/70.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 256 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Err http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main pulseaudio amd64 1:1.0-0ubuntu3.1
  Connection failed
Failed to fetch http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pulseaudio/pulseaudio_1.0-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
$
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, it turns out that the server I pointed to was stale.

I will post the steps to fix the problem here (for my own reference and for others who run into similar problems).

1. Try `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install XXX` first - your own cache may be stale.  If that fails, go to 2-5.
2. Find a new server that is up-to-date, fast, and nearby from this [list](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors).
3. Use the instructions [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-select-fastest-mirror-in-ubuntu.html) for pointing to the new server.
4. `sudo apt-get update` after pointing to the new server.
5. `sudo apt-get install XXX`

The surprising thing is ubuntu's own servers appeared to be stale:

`tw.archive.ubuntu.com`

It would be nice if Ubuntu would fix these issues so it would be friendlier for new, non-technical users (or at least be more obvious: perhaps warning about a stale server during `apt-get install`).

Comment: You can check the status of the mirrors on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors